# Solving coupled complex ODEs with Python (Propagating two time-dependent signals in space)

Tags: python, solver, ode, odeint

Im trying to simulate wave-propagation in nonlinear material. I consider a fundamental wave ![A(z, t)] which enters the material with a defined signal-shape for z0, and a second harmonic wave B(z, t) with B(z0, t) = 0. Nonlinear effects in the material causing the fundamental wave A(z, t) to generate second harmonics B(z, t) while travelling though the material in z-direction.

the generation can be described as follows:

[image]

I tried to implement this using Pythons odeint like this:

```
def NL_coupling(t, Amp, c):
A, B = Amp
rho1, rho2 = c

return [1j * rho1 * B * np.conj(A),
        1j * rho2 * A * A]

solveNonlinear = integrate.ode(NL_coupling).set_integrator('zvode', method='bdf')
solveNonlinear.set_f_params(paramCoupling).set_initial_value([A, B], 0)
```

When I try to iterate the solver, I get the following error:

```
ZWORK length needed, LENZW (=I1), exceeds LZW (=I2)
```

I used the same solver before to propagate a single wave without coupling which worked fine. keep in mind that A and B are (complex) arrays containing the time-resolved pulseform. 
So how could I possibly do this?
I tried solving the ODE for a single timepoint t, so that [A, B] is a list containing only two elements, than iterating over the whole signal. But since the solver does not calculate the value for the exact same point every time, this method does not really provide useful results.

Thanks for your help

Comment: *" keep in mind that A and B are (complex) arrays..."*   The ODE solvers in SciPy expect the state vector to be a 1-d array.  You'll have to wrap your function in something that flattens the arrays into a single 1-d array.

Comment: I tried to simply concatinate A and B to pass them, split them up inside the method and then concat the results to return it. However, the result was far from what I expected and I thought it may not be the right way to do it because of the way odeint works. But as I know you have worked with odeint much more than I have (and wrote the odeintw wrapper, thanks for that), I might check that option out again. Thanks for your quick response

Comment: Assuming `A` and `B` are 1-d, you would need to concatenate them so that the result is still 1-d (e.g. `np.concatenate((A, B))`, and not `np.array([A, B])`).  Then in `NL_coupling`, do something like `n = len(Amp) // 2; A = Amp[:n]; B = Amp[n:]`.  (That assumes `A` and `B`  have the same length.  Adjust the code as needed if they don't.)  Use the same concatenation method to assemble the return value of `NL_coupling`.

Comment: By the way, there is a potential problem with using `ode` with the `zvode` solver for this problem.  In the "Notes" section of the [ode documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html), read the boxed note under "zvode" about the analyticity requirement.  There is a complex conjugate of `A` in your equations.  The conjugate operation is not analytic.

Comment: There is a minus sign in your equation that is not reflected in code? To test the solver/solution, use one of the other solvers and do like in the comment 2 above only with a factor of 4, `A=Amp[:N]+Amp[N:2*N]*1j; B=Amp[2*N:3*N]+Amp[3*N:]*1j;` and assemble the return value via `np.concatenate((dA.real,dA.imag,dB.real, dN.imag))`.